# Is there an API to push a different notification to a million devices in one shot?

Tags: java, azure, amazon-web-services, notifications, push-notification

All the third party services I checked out like AWS, OneSignal, BulkPush, Pushy, Parse etc., all these can broadcast the same message to a million devices. Some other services like Azure, OneSignal etc. can push messages to many devices with the same tag too.

**Requirement:** What I need is to push different task notifications to thousands of users(ios/android devices) from my server application. Each notification sent to each device is different, as I am passing a taskid along with it. Suppose I use Azure's tag based approach, each notification I send will have its own tag. Otherwise I will have to do a for loop and push notifications one by one which will take me hours. Else I will have to implement multi-threading and my server should handle the overhead.

Is there any API(preferably a Java SDK) that could take an array of notifications with their corresponding unique message and device registration ids and push those asynchronously?

Comment: There are several ways to solve this. Aside from Azure's notification hubs, there are different libraries as well as 3rd-party services. Unfortunately asking for 3rd-party service / tool recommendations is off-topic. And just for clarification: Neither AWS nor Azure are *libraries*.

Comment: Thanks David for the clarification. :) I have edited the question. I had searched and failed to find a service that could asynchronously push different messages to different devices in one go. Please let me know if such a service exists.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Notification Hub's templates would allow you to send a different notification content to each device. You would need to specify the template ID at registration time, and then provide a mapping from each template ID to your taskId when you issue your push request. You might run into some request limits trying to pass in all of your taskIds at once, though.

Documentation is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530748.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I just came across [Catapush](http://www.catapush.com/features/push-personalization) which looks like a service i have been searching for. It uses XMPP which ensures asynchronous behaviour. They also mention this as their feature: **Customize text for different recipients with variable [text] for massive sending as well. With Catapush and all info have you can send custom messages which will be personalized automatically with any information you'd like** It is also reliable, traceable(you can track the delivery of your push notifications) and scalable. Seriously???

I have not implemented this. If any of you have experience with Catapush, please share if this could be the answer for the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could use Parse's cloud code or even their REST API to create those Push notifications and send them. Check this out: https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#push-notifications

I believe there should be something similar for AWS too. I've never used it though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) From what i understood, Parse allows you to send the same message to devices subscribed to a particular channel. Using advanced targeting, it allows you to conditionally send messages to a channel's subscribers too. But **every single notification i send to every device** will be different. Then i will have to either loop and push them synchronously or implement multi-threading and push each message on a separate thread. Is there an api that would take my array of notifications and push it asynchronously for me?

Comment: This is a product recommendation.